# How to use go:embed to read application properties

Tags: go, embed, viper

I use viper to load runtime environment specific property files (located under ./configs/*.conf). I am looking to see how I can embed these files in the binary.

Following snippet that loads the files

```
viper.AddConfigPath("./configs")
viper.SetConfigName("app_dev.conf")
viper.ReadInConfig()
```

I have tried using the following embed directive

```
//go:embed configs/*.conf
var resources embed.FS
```

However getting an error that it cannot load the property files. It works, as expected, if I add the config folder in the same location as the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can use io.reader to load Viper config

```
data, _ := _configFile.ReadFile("configs/app_dev.conf")
err = viper.ReadConfig(strings.NewReader(string(data)))
```

Comment: But wasn't embedding the files the core of your question?

Comment: use `bytes.NewReader(data)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how an answer to the original question (with file embedding) could look like:

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "embed"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
)

//go:embed configs/*.conf
var resources embed.FS

data, err := resources.ReadFile("configs/app_dev.conf")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
err = viper.ReadConfig(bytes.NewReader(data))
```